# What were the pirates saying in Mysterious Island (1961)

Tags: dialogue, mysterious-island

During the last 1/4 of the movie Mysterious Island (1961) the stranded soldiers are attacked by pirates who have several lines of dialogue in a language other than English.

Is this an actual real world language, and if so what were they saying?

I do not have a time index, but there is only one scene, and it is distinct enough that anyone familiar with the movie should be able to recognize it.

Comment: Time index is 1:11:00 on this copy available on Archive.org. The subtitles don't cover the non-English parts; https://archive.org/details/mysterious-island-1961_202008

Comment: Q. Why are pirates called pirates? A. Because they arrrrr!